# Transferring data to Db issue, how to increase the transferring speed of data from java application to database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, garbage-collection

In my application I am taking data from file and transferring to database. I have 400 000 records. First it transfers data fast up to 10 000 records after that it updating very slowly. Hw to increase the performance of transferring data to db?

is there any problem with gc?

This is my code:

```
package com.fileupload;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.swing.text.ZoneView;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

public class SendDataToDb extends HttpServlet{
PreparedStatement ps = null;
HttpSession hs;
Connection con1;
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

     hs = request.getSession(false);
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xlsx","root","Inf123#");
        ps = con1.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO userdetails(ID, NAME, AGE, GENDER,ADDRESS, ZONEID, LOCATION) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        processOneSheet("C:/Users/Penchalaiah/Desktop/New folder/"+hs.getAttribute("filename1"));
        System.out.println("clossing the connnection");
        ps.close();
        con1.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

}

public void processOneSheet(String filename) throws Exception {
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
    XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
    SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

    XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst);

    // To look up the Sheet Name / Sheet Order / rID,
    //  you need to process the core Workbook stream.
    // Normally it's of the form rId# or rSheet#
    InputStream sheet2 = r.getSheet("rId2");
    InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet2);
    parser.parse(sheetSource);
    sheet2.close();
}

public XMLReader fetchSheetParser(SharedStringsTable sst) throws SAXException {
    XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader("org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser");
    ContentHandler handler = new SheetHandler(sst);
    parser.setContentHandler(handler);
    return parser;
}

/** 
 * See org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler javadocs 
 */
private  class SheetHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private SharedStringsTable sst;
    private String lastContents;
    private boolean nextIsString;
    String id;
    String names;
    String age;
    String gender;
    String address;

    int i = 1;

    private SheetHandler(SharedStringsTable sst) {
        this.sst = sst;

    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // c => cell
        if(name.equals("c")) {
            // Print the cell reference
            // Figure out if the value is an index in the SST
            String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
            if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                nextIsString = true;
            } else {
                nextIsString = false;
            }
        }
        // Clear contents cache
        lastContents = "";
        //System.out.println("===>"+lastContents+"<====");
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        // Process the last contents as required.
        // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
        if(nextIsString) {
            int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastContents);
            lastContents = new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
            nextIsString = false;

        }

        // v => contents of a cell
        // Output after we've seen the string contents




        if(name.equals("v")) {
            System.out.print(lastContents+"\t");

            if(i == 1){
                id = lastContents;

                System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
            }
            if(i == 2){
                names = lastContents;

                System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
            }
            if(i == 3){
                age = lastContents;

                System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
            }
            if(i == 4){
                gender = lastContents;
                System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
            }
            if(i == 5){
                address = lastContents;

                System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
                insertInToDb(id, names, age, gender, address);
                i = 0;
            }

            i++;


        }

    }


    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        lastContents += new String(ch, start, length);
    }
}

    public void insertInToDb(String id,String names,String age, String gender,String address){

        try {

            ps.setString(1, id);
            ps.setString(2, names);
            ps.setString(3, age);
            ps.setString(4, gender);
            ps.setString(5, address);
            ps.setString(6, (String)hs.getAttribute("zoneId1"));
            ps.setString(7, (String)hs.getAttribute("location1"));
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How much time is it taking now to execute this piece of code? What improvements in terms of time are you looking at by saying improve the speed?

Comment: it's taking more than 30 minutes , i need to improve in terms of time

Comment: Have you tried reading all the contents first and make a collection of insert statements, then doing a batch operation?

Answer (score 1):

Executing one batch operation for multiple records is much faster than executing each insert query for multiple records.

You can create a batch of 10000 or whatever you want and then execute the batch.

```
 Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("driver class");
            con = DriverManager.
                    getConnection("connectionUrlString","password");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            pstm = con.prepareStatement("your insert command );
            pstm .setInt(1, 3000); //set all parameters            
            pst.addBatch();
            int count[] = pst.executeBatch();
            for(int i=1;i<=count.length;i++){
                System.out.println("Query "+i+" has effected "+count[i]+" records");
            }
            con.commit();
            pst.close();
            con.close();
```